# How do you style the command buttons so they are bigger?

Tags: visualforce, css

I have a few command buttons on 2 different VF pages. How do I style the buttons so they are bigger?

```
<apex:commandButton value="do something" action="{!myAction}" />
```

When I do it, it looks off [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OK I feel like this nails it!**

I fought with the answers above, not because they were incorrect but because they are most likely out of date and Salesforce has changed.
The btn class answer should have worked and so should the bootstrap answer.
But both were difficult to get working.
Also remove Salesforce Stylesheets is never the right answer, because using standard lookup fields is so useful.

While working through the bootstrap idea I found salesforce was changing my elements class tags, it was adding btn as a class even though my styleclass did not have it. btn is a class in bootstrap and salesforce was overriding it, hence bootstrap was failing.

so I removed "btn" from my code and added this JS to stop salesforce from adding "btn". Added JS at the bottom of the VF page before the

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input.btn').removeClass('btn');
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

my bootstrapped button now looks like this:

```
<div id="buttons" class="col-sm-12 btn-group-lg " role="group" aria-label="...">
    <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn-primary btn-lg" value="Search" action="{!runQuery}" rerender="theTable,previewbtn,subjectPanel" />
</div>
```

this is what matters, note the missing btn class:
styleClass="btn-primary btn-lg"

Comment: I have removed your upvote request as including that in answers is against our community standards.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to use a apex:commandLink and style it as a button, then adjust the padding to make it whatever size you want.

```
<apex:commandLink styleClass="btn" style="padding: 4px; text-decoration: none;" 
                  value="Test" action="{!myAction}"></apex:commandLink>
```

This gives you a button the same style and size as a standard salesforce button. Adjust the padding up to get a bigger button.

In this case you would not use use standardStylesheets=false. Just be warned that the "btn" class is an internal to salesforce and *could* change down the road.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap. Then you can use bootstrap class `btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block`. otherwise you can give width and height as per your requirement and it will increase your button bigger.

Answer (score -2):

Apply standardStylesheets="false" in the  tag

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false">
</apex:page>
```